# Actionscript 3 static analyzer with @NotNull/@Nullable support

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, static-analysis

I would like to use static analysis to prevent "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference".

As far as I know there is a static analyzers for Java that use @NotNull/@Nullable. Programmer explicitly express his intentions by specifying those annotations for every member/function/argument so that tool can verify if everything is corrent and every @Nullable -> @NotNull conversion is made with a check for null. For me it would be more comfortable to only specify @Nullable so that everything else could be treated like @NotNull but it's not necessary.

I wonder if there are free tools of that kind for Actionscript 3?

I have FlashBuilder 4.5 license but beyond that I'd prefer not to purchase anything else. I heard that IntelliJ IDEA might have such a thing but it only works with Actionscript in Ultimate Edition which is not free :(

### So the questions are:

1. Is there such static analyzer for Actionscript 3?
2. How much will it costs if it's not free?
3. Is there any other solutions for preventing 1009 error except "check everything and transform your code into a mess".

### Update

There is no full answer given :( But **weltraumpirat**'s answer is the best so far. I consider to use naming convention for nullable functions: Try*, Find*, *OrNull, *IfAny etc. Names become longer but reliability is more important. Thank you weltraumpirat! Bounty is your but I will not mark the answer as 'accepted' since it's not full and I hope at some time somebody will answer with a link to desired static analyzer :)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no static analysis tool for ActionScript that can actually prevent null reference errors - AS is a dynamic language, and quite a lot of what makes it a good language happens outside of what the compiler (or a static analysis tool, for that matter) can verify.

What you can and should do, though, is design your code in a way that *prevents* null references in the first place, and allows *meaningful error messages* to help you find errors faster.

Think of it this way: **If a variable instance is not supposed to be null at a certain point, should the program be allowed to run anyway?**  In most cases, the answer is clearly: No, it shouldn't!

For example, instead of preventing the null reference, a common mistake is to add null checks at every conceivable point in your program, like this:

```
function myMethod( something:* ) : void {
    if ( something != null) {
       doStuff();
    }
}
```

The result of this is that, rather than having an error thrown (which would enable you to find the name of the method and line number where the crash occurred, in order to track down the problem), the program will keep running, but nothing happens.  Now when you perform a manual test, you will see: **nothing**.  And there will be no indication of what went wrong.

A much better way to deal with null references is to

- Make sure none of your methods return null.  *Ever*.

  This can be achieved by returning default values, such as:

  ```
  function getPropertyValue() : String { 
      return _property != null ? _property : "";
  }
  ```

  And of course, the default value could be something meaningful, such as `"Property did not have a value."`, so that in your UI, you'd notice the problem right away, without compromising the rest of the program. (Note that this does not only work for getters, but for any method that returns a value - I simply chose an obvious example.)

  If you really can't get around returning null for some reason, make sure your method name reflects that, so when you use it, you *know* to expect possible null values:

  ```
   function getPropertyValueOrNull() : String {
       return _property;
   }
  ```
- Instead of useless null checks, create validation methods at critical points in your application, and throw meaningful errors to point to the cause of the problem:

  ```
  function tryExecuteImportantFunction() : void {
      try {
           validate();
           executeImportantFunction();
      } catch ( e:Error ) {
           trace( "Validation failed:" + e.message );
      }
  }

  function validate() : void {
      if (_requiredProperty1 == null) 
          throw new Error ( "_requiredProperty1 was null, but should always contain a string value.");
      if (_requiredProperty2 == null) 
          throw new Error ( "_requiredProperty2 was null, but should always contain a dictionary.");
  }
  ```

  Meaningful errors should be caught and forwarded to the log or a debugging console, so that you always know where to look for the cause, and get an idea what you have to do to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Unfortunately functions returning 'null' is not the only source of the problem. There is also uninitialized members (and that also could be verified by compiler if only AS3 would allow to initialize 'const' fields in constructors with arguments involved). Also nontrivial chain of calls at the program initialization could lead to executing stuff that is not initialized yet (that could be handled though). And a lot of different things. The main problem is that project is too big (300k+ lines) to control it without instrumental support.

Comment: For the uninitialized members - that's where the validation methods come into play.  If you use try/catch blocks, you will be able to handle shortcomings, and you can have a central place to check for everything that is required to run a particular task - instead of having null checks distributed all over your classes.

Comment: I still can't get it. The project is a game so there is no important/not important methods and classes. Also problem is definitely not with an input data (network) so I don't see any points where validation could be performed. Those errors is just a small local mistakes (not far from misprints) which is natural to humans. Same with try/catch blocks - I don't any points the're more reasonable then in another places. Also all those validation and checks are in runtime and therefore will slow down execution.

Comment: You said "AS is a dynamic language, and quite a lot of what makes it a good language happens outside of what the compiler can verify." But I don't use dynamic classes but Object for small amount specific cases. And I don't want them to be checked. But with strict mode and non-dynamic classes I don't see any reasons that make those static checks I mentioned impossible.

Comment: What I meant is that there is no way to be sure with static analysis only. Which is why I for one wouldn't trust it enough to not have validation or error checks, and I certainly wouldn't waste time trying to write a tool that's smart enough to check for dynamic stuff, too.  Of course, these errors are human - we wouldn't need any error checks if we didn't make them!  The idea is to have a centralized place that checks if all required parameters are in place.  This serves both as a safe guard, and as *documentation*, because it describes a *requirement* - that belongs in the code!

Comment: "validation" in this case means "see if all the parts are in place" - that is not limited to user input.  Good places to put these are: after an `init` method, or at the top of a `render` method, a game loop, or an event triggered action.  Each validation consists only of a few simple if statements that check for `null` - you'd have to have a *damn lot* of those to even notice a slow down effect.  The try/catch blocks will only be costly, if there are errors - in which case they shouldn't be your first concern.

Comment: Your answer is best so far. Even though it's just a part of the answer :) Bounty is your. I consider to use naming convention for nullable functions: Try*, Find*, *OrNull, *IfAny etc. Names become longer but reliability is more important.

Answer (score 0):

most usefull in this case should be getters and setters  :

```
protected var _value:Object;

public function get value():Object{
    if(_value){
        return _value;
    }
    trace("missing object");// or throw "missing object error"
    return new Object();
}

public function set value(v:Object):void {
    _value = v;
}
```

EDIT:

Also additional thing for null checking might be read describeType() xml and check accessable values if exist .

Comment: Yes, if all you want to do is get a property value.  The concept I described in my answer works for any method that has a return value.

Comment: but You didnt mentioned getters and setters that might be very usefull here.

Answer (score 0):

I second whatever weltraumpirat said about programming in a way that you avoid nulls altogether. However, in my experience this is not always possible. During a recent project we did, we were retrieving and generating a lot of dynamic data that changed types and shapes.

Network timeouts, callback exits and anything else unexpected for that matter caused nulls to stop the application. We knew that the null error was not significant and that we expected it in a lot of scenarios.

This called for Dynamic Error Handling for all error cases in the game. try catch statements were either too slow or required a lot of maintenance. The Flash Player provides one method to handle this, although it may not be the most suitable solution to every problem set. It's the "UncaughtErrorEvent" introduced after the Flash Player 10.1 release.

[Flash Player UncaughtErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvents.html)

Moreover, there's a really good library that can handle this. here:

[Global Error Handler](https://github.com/jonasmonnier/jonAS3)

Finally, if you look at the future road-map of Flash Player development, you'll notice that static typing, overloading and lotsa big changes coming to the platform. But for now, that's the best solution I have used.

[Flash Player Roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html)

Comment: The UncaughtErrorEvents should only be a last resort to exit your application gracefully when something goes horribly wrong - it should never be your main error handling strategy!  If you use a centralized class to handle all errors, you end up with a monolithic monster that breaks all dependency management and makes your code impossible to maintain.  Also, errors can happen for so many reasons - OP asked about compilation time checks. Synchronous tasks, such as network access, callbacks etc. have their own error events, which can and should be used to deal with their respective causes.

Comment: I know about UncaughtErrorEvent but right now we cannot use 10.1 player (some of our users don't have it according to statistics we gathered). Also I don't see any errors that could be really _handled_ by a global error handler. The only thing that could be done that way is an error reporting (which we already have w/o UEE). Also these reports have no info about place where the exception happened in release version of flash player so I had to implement some hand-made stack tracing. And I actually did it :) But the point is: errors should be _prevented_ rather then fixed as report arrived.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give FlexPMD a try. It is closely related to Java's PMD and will find smells in your source code by applying rules.

Adobe released it as open source and you can get it at sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexpmd/home/Home/

Here's a small introduction video: http://www.riagora.com/2010/04/introduction-to-flex-pmd/

As far as I know it can be easily integrated with Flex Builder but should also work with other IDEs like IntelliJ and FDT or even the command line.

Comment: As far as I can see it have no support for main feature requested - @Nullable/@NotNull. So it's an off-topic. I've tried to run it few times but I found nothing interesting in those reports. And also no way to suppress warning in places where rules were violated intentionally - so far it's useless for me. Maybe I was just not so attentive...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with gui programming is, that there is always some sort of state. The problem described is basically having a valid and invalid state. As a experienced Flex developer i can tell, there is not such a state as an invalid state. null is a valid reference so we have to deal with it.

The first question i'd ask is: why is null bad? null is needed to clean things up and make sure we get the idea of a state, with no data.

Flex has the idea of a live cycle, which basically leads to a very interesting behavior. When a component is initialized, its children are not. So basically this is a very fragile system on the first look. Properties are mostly delegated to other component aggregated by a view (regarding the view layer). But the same could happen to the model, controller or service layer.

So, how to deal with that problem? I think it is a design decision in first place. When null is looked as the value breaking a system, the system is almost broken by default. I think of null as the easiest way to indicate the absence of data.

A different approach would be the creation of default models. Models are from my point of view the only real bummer, since all other components rely on them.

```
package net.icodeapps.examples.model
{
  public class User
  {
  }
}

package net.icodeapps.examples.model
{
  public class DefaultUser extends User
  {
  }
}
```

Having such default models could make it easy to bootstrap an application with valid, not null reference and values, but there has to be an a decision made as well, whether or not a default model is being processed or not.

Also, and here is the most important part: kicking null out of the app will kill the memory eventually, if the system is not thought through properly.

Comment: There is a fields that is not supposed to be null at all (no absence of data is supposed to have a place). With 'default' and 'dummy' object I only prevent spread of the error further (when exception happens - part of code handling some event will not be executed at the same time some part of it already does). But it only masks the problem - this absence is not supposed to be there at all. With @Nullable/@NotNull it is possible to explain your intentions to computer so that he could check everything for you with necessary knowledge. Same way compiler helps you when you specify variables types.

Comment: I totally get the idea. But in fact the question could be easily answered with: no, no, no. I'm just trying to point out, that there are ways to work with null. That's all i just tried to add.